# does not work - zf2 CRUD mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to build a CRUD using doctrine 2 and zend framework 2 using mongodb.

I followed some tutorials, but it still fails.

Follow the links:
http://www.bigwisu.com/2012/10/03/zend-framework-2-doctrine-odm
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule

Below is the configuration used in the project:

module.doctrine_mongodb.local.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server'    => 'localhost',
                'port'      => '27017',
                'dbname'    => 'teste',
                'options'   => array()
            ),
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache'     => 'array',
                'driver'             => 'odm_default',
                'generate_proxies'   => true,
                'proxy_dir'          => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',
                'generate_hydrators' => true,
                'hydrator_dir'       => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator',
                'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',
                'default_db'         => 'teste',
                'filters'            => array()
            )
        ),

        'documentmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
            //    'connection'    => 'odm_default',
            //    'configuration' => 'odm_default',
            //    'eventmanager' => 'odm_default'
            )
        ),
        'eventmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array()
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

module.config.php
add

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(           
            __NAMESPACE__.'_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',         
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Document')
            ),
            'odm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Document' => __NAMESPACE__.'_driver'
                )
            )                  
        )
    )
```

Document\Artigo.php

```
<?php
namespace Site\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document(collection="artigo") */
class Artigo
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $nome;

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $nome
     */
    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $id
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $nome
     */
    public function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

}
```

And controller:

```
<?php

namespace Site\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Site\Document\Artigo;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default'); 
        $artigo = new Artigo();
        $artigo>setNome("teste");
        $dm->persist($artigo);
        $dm->flush();

        return new ViewModel(array('teste'=>'acho que deu'));
    }
}
```

No error happens and also does not insert the record.
You know what can be?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on the DoctrineMongoODMModule, and have my own libs that can help hooking up zf2 doctrine and mongo. If you want to create a json REST endpoint for a doctrine document, here's how...

Add the following to your composer.json:

```
    "superdweebie/doctrine-extensions-module": "dev-master"
```

The update composer.

Register these modules in your `application.config.php`:

```
'modules' => array(
    'Sds\Zf2ExtensionsModule',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineMongoODMModule',       
    'Sds\DoctrineExtensionsModule',       
),
```

Then add this one of your module configs:

```
'sds' => [
    'doctrineExtensions' => [
        'doctrine' => [
            'driver' => 'odm_default',
            'eventmanager' => 'odm_default',
            'configuration' => 'odm_default',
            'documentManager' => 'doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default',
        ],
        'extensionConfigs' => [
            'Sds\DoctrineExtensions\Rest' => true,
        ],
    ],               
],

'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'Sds\Zf2ExtensionsModule\RestRoute' => [
            'type' => 'Sds\Zf2ExtensionsModule\RestRoute',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/rest',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'Sds\DoctrineExtensionsModule\Controller\JsonRestfulController'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Then add the `@Sds\Rest` annotation to your document:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Sds\DoctrineExtensions\Annotation\Annotations as Sds;

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 * @Sds\Rest
 */
class MyDocument{
    ...
}
```

That's it.

Now you can use the REST service like this:

The rest endpoint is at `http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument`

To get json back from any request, include the `accept: "application/json"` header. To send json with any request, include the `content-type: "application/json"` header.

To read a single item, send a `GET` request with an id:

```
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument/itemid
```

To read a list, send a `GET` request to:

```
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument
```

When listing products, by default the first 30 will be returned. To alter this use the range header, eg:

```
range: items=5-10
```

Even if more than 30 items are requested, a maxim of 30 will be returned. The response will have the following header to indicate which items have been returned and how many there are in total:

```
Content-Range: items 0-24/66
```

The list can be queried with a query string. eg:

```
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument?fieldA=filterValue
```

The list can be sorted with a query string. eg will sort acceding by type, then descending by name:

```
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument?sort(+type,-name)
```

To create, send a `POST` request, with json content. eg:

```
request-
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument

content-
{id: 1234, fieldA: 'abc'}
```

To update, send a `PUT` request, with json content to a specific id. eg:

```
request-
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument/1234

content-
{fieldA: 'def'}
```

To delete, send a `DELETE` request to a specific id. eg:

```
http://mysite.com/rest/mydocument/1234
```

The beginning of docs for these modules can be found at https://sds.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. There are other functions not described here to integrate with the dojo client side framework, control serialization, and access control.